# Any reason why my $.ajax success callback is not executed in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Today i discovered that my dev version of my website do not execute success callback, but all other javascript and jquery code is running good. Even my ajax request is performed and i can see response in firebug.

```
$('#login').submit(function(){
    var email = $('#l_email').val();
    var pass = $('#l_pass').val();
    if(email && pass != ''){
        var str = decodeURIComponent($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg == 'OK'){
                    window.location = 'index.php'
                }else if (msg == 'NOT_OK'){
                    if(lang == 'lv'){
                        alert(message);
                    }else if(lang == 'ru'){
                        alert(message);
                    }
                }else if (msg == 'EMAIL_NOT_VALID'){
                    if(lang == 'lv'){
                        alert(message);
                    }else if(lang == 'ru'){
                        alert(message);
                    }      
                }
            }
         });
    }else{
        alert('That form is empty.');
    }
    return false;
});
```

The thing is $.ajax part executes fine and i can see response in firebug "OK". But redirect is not happening and even if i replace that redirect with something like alert or console.log nothing comes up.

What could cause this? It's really hard to track since firebug gives no errors.

**Resolved:** *by suggestion of Reigel, wrapping success callback data return in $.trim();*

Comment: are you getting the right/expected values when you do `alert(msg)`?

Comment: why don't you implement error: function? maybe there is something wrong?

Comment: What you mean? My code won't run success callback so that alert is never fired. But yeah msg returns back as OK and if else is not performed.

Comment: i agree, are you sure it's going into the msg=='OK' part? maybe you would like to do an alert and show what's in you msg variable.

Comment: also is the index.php path correct?

Comment: I suspected there are "spaces" in there since it's a html. try `success: function(msg){ var msg= $.trim(msg); ..... }`

Comment: Use the failure callback as well. And do the alert(msg) before you enter any control structure. You might want to try setting "async" to false, too.

Comment: @all I might have to look in other parts of my code because i used this for 2 months with no problems.
@Jules I can see that i got right values back and request was 200 OK so i don't think failure will do any good.
@melaos console.log(msg) returns OK as expected.
@Reigel will try, but it did work before.

Comment: is the `message` variable defined ? Can't see it defined in this section of the code

Comment: @Dan yes i just replaced it theres actual text in there

Comment: @Reigel - hmm var msg = $.trim(msg); did the trick. But why i wonder? I have been using that 2 months already and login.php is sending non spaced string back.

Comment: I would look at your server first, since this where you initially echo from to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding an `else { alert('No match for msg'); }` block to the code of your success function, maybe you'll see that msg does not match any of your IFs statements.

[jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says the signature of the success function should be: `success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)` so I guess msg if not getting the response status but rather the data.

Comment: msg is getting right value back, but for some reason i had to use $.trim(msg); so it works now as expected. But the thing is i have been using that code for 2 months with no $.trim